# Slick select using value object (extending AnyVal)

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I am using Slick 2.1.0 with Scala 2.10.
I have a value object (`EMail`) that I map to a `VARCHAR` column.

```
object EMail {
  import java.util.regex.Pattern
  val emailRegex = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)

  val empty = EMail("x@y.com")
}

case class EMail(value: String) extends AnyVal with MappedTo[String] {
  def isValid: Boolean = EMail.emailRegex.matcher(value).find

  def validate: EMail = {
    assert(isValid)
    EMail(value.trim.toLowerCase)
  }

  override def toString = validate.value
}
```

The `Column` definition is:

```
def email = column[Option[EMail]]("email_address")
```

This is my attempt at writing a finder:

```
def findByEmail(email: Option[EMail]): Option[User] =
  database.withSession { implicit session: Session =>
    queryAll.filter(e => e.email.isDefined && e.email === email).firstOption
  }
```

This is the error message I get:

`[error] Users.scala:52: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value BooleanCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean]
[error]  and value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[Boolean]]]
[error]  match expected type scala.slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
[error]     queryAll.filter(_.email === email.map(_.value)).firstOption
[error]                    ^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass an `Option[EMail]` to your method, you could simply make:

```
def findByEmail(email: EMail): Option[User] = {
  database.withSession { implicit session =>
    queryAll.filter(_.email === email).firstOption
  }
}
```

If you really need an `Option[EMail]]` as the input parameter, you should try the following:

```
def findByEmail(emailOpt: Option[EMail]): Option[User] = {
  emailOpt.flatMap { email =>
    database.withSession { implicit session =>
      queryAll.filter(_.email === email).firstOption
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I discovered you are correct. https://github.com/mslinn/slick_2.1.0_mappings/blob/master/src/main/scala/App.scala I had thought to delete this posting